# Android Studio 3 - how to add cloud endpoints module

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, android-studio-3.0, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

In Android Studio 3 "Add Module" no longer as the option to add a Google Cloud module such as Cloud Endpoints. - How can we add an Endpoints module (and firebase for example) now?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/docs/) it is not supported in Android Studio 3.0

Answer (score 0):

@jkaps9 I believe this to be the case since I have been trying to set up Google Cloud Endpoints for the last week & a half. Despite everything I have tried, that is, following Google's instructions and or some tinkering, it just won't work.

I realized however that I did upgrade to Android Studio 3.0 [which says "however, your existing projects with cloud backends will continue to work in Android Studio."](http://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/docs/)  I now thinking that it's affecting the setup/project.